# Executar o webservice via CMD retorna NULL

Tags: php, web-service, windows, cmd

Estou com o código abaixo que preciso executá-lo a cada hora. 
Esse script executando pelo navegador, retorna os dados corretamente.
Pretendia executá-lo via tarefas agendadas, pelo CMD através das linhas de execução:

`c:/caminhocorreto/php -c c:/caminho/para/o/php.ini [ -f ] c:/caminho/para/o/script.php`  ou `php -f c:/caminho/para/o/script.php`

O problema que pelo primeiro comando, retorna que não encontrou as bibliotecas (definidas no php.ini):
`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '${path}\binaries\php\ext\php_xsl.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. in Unknown on line 0`

No segundo comando, ele cai no `catch` e me retorna NULL. Tentando executar uma página simples.

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 900);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include('../includes/class.usuario.php');
include('../includes/conexao.php'   );

$params = array(
    'usuario' => $usuario,
    'senha' => $senha,
    'quantidade' => 10
);

$wsdl = 'http://site_de_consulta_webservice?WSDL';

$options = array(
        'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
        'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout'=>15,
        'trace'=>true,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'exceptions'=>true,
    );
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);        
    $data = $soap->obterPacotePosicoes($params);        

}
catch (SoapFault $fault){       
    echo "\n\n".$fault->getMessage();
}

$i = 0;

foreach($data->return as $posicao)
{
    $cod_macro = $posicao->codigoMacro;

    //INSERT DOS DADOS NO BANCO DE DADOS A CADA EXECUÇÃO DO SISTEMA!
}
```

Alguém sabe dizer se há problema em consultar webservice via prompt? Ou se há algo errado? E porque o primeiro comando acontece a falha de encontrar as libs?

**EDIT**

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2014 20:26:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

C:\>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
yaz
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No CMD, execute isso: `php -v`. Execute também `php -m`. Poste na pergunta o resultado de ambos. Executando pelo browser, faça outro teste. Salve um arquivo como "info.php". Nesse arquivo, coloque apenas isso `<?php phpinfo();`. Poste um printscreen do que resultou.  (Isso não é a solução. São testes de diagnóstico.)

Comment: @DanielOmine isto?

Comment: ok, execute isso via browser: `<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions());`. Poste o que resultou. Aproveita e executa esse mesmo via CMD.

Comment: @DanielOmine, feito... utilizando `C:\>php -r print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` direto via CMD o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Uma dúvida que tenho é, no primeiro comando é declarado o caminho completo do compilador do php `c:/caminhocorreto/php`. Já no segundo é acessado por um alias. Esse alias leva ao mesmo compilador do caminho absoluto usado no primeiro comando? O php.ini em ambos é o mesmo? No resultado do phpinfo() podemos ver o path do php.ini. Esse é o mesmo caminho usado no primeiro comando? A suspeita inicial é que tem mais de uma instalação do php ou mais de um arquivo de inicializações (php.ini)

Comment: @DanielOmine verificando aqui, realmente no primeiro caminho eu estava usando outro caminho de php.ini. Agora ambas opções retornam `NULL` e não dá erro. Um erro eu descobri, mas não resolvi o principal rsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine o erro é que por CMD ele não adiciona os `includes`. É possível tratar isso para executar corretamente?

Comment: Você fala dos includes do usuario e conexao? Se for isso, evite caminho relativo. Defina caminho absoluto. `include(__DIR__.'/../includes/class.usuario.php');`

Comment: @DanielOmine isso mesmo, acabei de encontrar aqui também, testei e funcionou perfeitamente.